# Magento ajax form validation

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, magento

I have a form in Magento that I build in code, and that works with ajax, which I need to validate.

I would like to be able to use Magento's built-in validation functionality, but I don't know how I would trigger it since the form is not submitted. The data is retrieved via ajax and outputted in a list below the form.

Is there someone who can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is the javascript code used to hande the ajax request. Its called by the onclick event of the button.

```
function advancedtranslateSearch(url){  
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
      method: 'get',
      parameters: $('search_form').serialize(),
      onSuccess: function(transport) {
          json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
          $('result').update('<div class="hor-scroll">'+json.records+'</div>');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you add "required-entry" class to your required field

Comment: Yes, the problem is that there's no actual submit. the "submit" button only triggers a javascript (ajax) function.

Comment: Show your javascript code, that you are using for sending data? I suppose, that you are not using form's onsubmit event, but it's better to bind data sending on this event.

Comment: Updated my post with the code. Indeed, I'm not using the onsubmit, but the onclick event.

Binding this to the onsubmit event would not be a problem, but how would I stop the page from refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use form's `onsubmit` event.
To prevent page from reloading you must return **false** value from your function.